# Migrate Magento 1.8.1.0 to Magento 2.0

Tags: magento-1.8, magento2

I want to Upgrade existing magento website with around 3000 products from magento 1.8.1.0 to magento 2.0.

Note : Design is custom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento did bring out a migration tool to transfer items from magento 1 to magento 2. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool.html.

You should be able to download the migration tool from here: http://packages.magento.com/#magento/data-migration-tool

Just note the migration tool is still in beta as is magento 2 but good luck!

Comment: what if that didn't help

Comment: Then you'll need to look at creating a module and mapping the data yourself. You might be able to export product to csv from magento 1 and then try importing into magento 2 but you will need to check all the fields when importing.